# If statement on whether one string, or list of strings

Tags: python

I have the following function. Ideally, I want to have either a single string or a list of strings passed as an input.  In either case, I need to use .upper on it.   But, when only a single string is passed, the iterator iterates through each character.  How can I have an if statement that tests whether a list of strings or a single string? (I can't seem to avoid the iterable nature of strings)

```
def runthis(stringinput):

    for t in stringinput:
        t = t.upper()
```

Comment: So, even if `stringinput` was a list of strings, your code wouldn't modify it.

Comment: Seems nicer to always accept a list of strings, which may contain only a single string. What is the value in letting the caller pass you an un-listed string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the type using `isinstance`.

```
def runthis(stringinput):
    if isinstance(stringinput, list):
        for t in stringinput:
            t = t.upper()
            # Some other code should probably be here.
    elif isinstance(stringinput, basestring):
        t = t.upper()
        # Some other code perhaps as well.
    else:
        raise Exception("Unknown type.")
```

Use `str` instead of `basestring` for Python 3.

Comment: thanks!  That worked well

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isinstance()` to check whether your function arg is of type `list` or not:

```
def to_upper(arg):
    if isinstance(arg, list):
        return [item.upper() for item in arg]  # This is called list comprehension
    else:
        return arg.upper()
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to explicitly check if the argument is a list or a string and handle it differently within conditional clauses.

An alternative that I think might be nicer (if it's suitable for your use case) might be the following:

```
def runthis(*stringinput):
    for t in stringinput:
        t = t.upper()
        print(t)
    print()

runthis("test") # TEST
runthis("another", "test")  # ANOTHER TEST
runthis(*["one", "final", "test"]) # ONE FINAL TEST
```

However, this approach isn't appropriate if calling code may provide lists without splatting it.

---

This approach relies on the usage of the `*` operator, which here is used in two different ways.

**In the function definition context** (`*stringinput`), this operator essentially makes `stringinput` a *variadic* argument; that is, an argument that "scoops up" all arguments passed to the function into a tuple, which for the purposes of `runthis` acts like a list (it can be iterated over). If I were to make a call `runthis("foo", "bar", "baz")`, `stringinput` would have the value `("foo", "bar", "baz")`.

You can read more about variadic arguments [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).

**In the function invocation context** (`runthis(*["one", "final", "test"])`), this operator will "splat" or unpack each element of the list. Essentially, `runthis(*["one", "final", "test"])` is equivalent to `runthis("one", "final", "test")`.

You can read more about splatting [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: hi, thanks for that.  what does the "*" do?

Comment: "*" is the splat operator. I'll edit my post to include more information about it.

Comment: @keynesiancross I've edited those details in now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `type()` function as so:

```
if type(stringinput) is list:
    #Your list code
elif type(stringinput) is str:
    #Your string code
else:
    #stringinput isn't a list or a string, throw an error
```